# Python os.system() input text to script

Tags: python, bash, os.system

I have a script that I need to automate, so it's a `.sh` script which I want to run inside a python script: something like this:

```
import os
os.system('./script.sh -p 1234')
```

The script `script.sh` needs the user to input 3 fields, 1) the sudo password, 2) a string and 3) a string.

```
Enter password for user: xxxx  #typed by me
Enter Auth Username: xxxx      #typed by me
Enter Auth Password: xxx       #typed by me
```

How can I make the python script to type/insert/pass those 3 needed values to `script.sh`.

Comment: It would be easier to modify the shell script to accept three parameters initially

Comment: yes I also thought of that, but the script changes daily and is being download from another server plus I need the sudo password.

Comment: that does indeed complicate things

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.Popen` to start the script and the `communicate` method to pass it input.  Something like this:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['./script.sh', '-p', '1234'], 
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(input='password\nauth username\nauth password\n')
```

Comment: I tried this, it seems to work, but I cannot tell because I can't see the script output, If I run the process with os.system() I can see the output on the python shell, nayway to get this ?

Comment: Do you see the line where it says, `stdout, stderr = p.communicate(...)`?  `stdout` contains the output from the script.

Comment: The `subprocess` documentation has more details about how everything works.

Comment: could you please explain me why the `password\nauth` ?

Comment: `\n` is a newline character.  Each `\n` is simulating you hitting the return key.

Comment: The first response is "password", the second response is "auth username", the third response is "auth password".  The `\n` is simply where you would hit "return" if you were typing this manually.